# Creating a dialog Window in a native Outlook add-in

Tags: visual-c++, atl

I'm creating a native C++ Outlook add-in (.dll) and started my Visual Studio 2013 project [using MS guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee941475(v=office.14).aspx). The idea is to get user input from a dialog box when the user clicks a Ribbon button and then act on the input after the dialog closes.

Where I need help is creating a Window in the ButtonClicked function. I've tried all the wrong ways which include MFC class wizard and ATL window (CAxDialogImpl). The common denominator is I don't have a valid parent window to create another window. Even if I get an active window handle from outlook.

Ideally, I wouldn't take a dependency on MFC but will use it if necessary. I'm looking for assistance creating a dialog/window, any ideas on how to achieve this?

I get C#/managed is the way to go, but the requirements dictate otherwise.

Comment: The question is not related to Outlook. Looks like it is for MFC/C++ help.

Comment: In what way is it unrelated to Outlook?

Comment: The asker knows the window handle, but he doesn't know how to show a dialog windows using MFC/ATL. So the question is not specific to Outlook.

Comment: the asker of what? I'm confused on where you are coming from. If a window handle is required, it will come from Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QI the `Application.ActiveWindow` property (it will be either `Explorer` or `Inspector` object) for `IOleWindow` and call `IOleWindow::GetWindow()`.